# javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Olá!

No meu código JavaScript recebo o seguinte erro:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined"

Como sou nova na área, não entendo muito bem como resolver o problema, podem ajudar-me ?

```
case 'multiple_2_3':

    total = 3 * self.card.quantity;
    $("#resume-odds").hide();
    //gains = (cota1 * cota2) * self.card.quantity + (cota1 * cota3) * self.card.quantity +  (cota2 * cota3) * self.card.quantity
    for (let i in self.card.bets) {
        let bet1 = self.card.bets[i];
        if(self.card.bets.length > i){
        for (let j = i + 1; j < self.card.bets.length; j++) {
            let bet2 = self.card.bets[j];
            gains += parseFloat(bet1.odd) * parseFloat(bet2.odd) * self.card.quantity;
        }
        }
    }

    break;
case 'multiple_2_4':
    total = 6 * self.card.quantity;
    $("#resume-odds").hide();

    for (let i in self.card.bets) {
        let bet1 = self.card.bets[i];
        for (let j = i + 1; j < self.card.bets.length; j++) {
            let bet2 = self.card.bets[j];
            gains += parseFloat(bet1.odd) * parseFloat(bet2.odd) * self.card.quantity;
        }
    }

    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro quer dizer que `bet1` não tem valor defenido. Ou seja, que quando fazer `let bet1 = self.card.bets[i];` o objeto ou array `.bets` não tem valor para a propriedade `i` (ou tem valor e ele é `undefined`).

Uma vez que tens `if(self.card.bets.length > i){` antes, isso garante que o `i` não é maior que a array, o que é bom, mas indica que a posição `i` dessa array é `undefined`. É aí que tens de procurar pelo problema e perceber porque isso aconteceu. Isso será já noutra pergunta talvez mas revê como constróis essa array e de onde vêm os valores.

Comment: eu já revi e parecem-me direitos , ele no primeiro for tem valores no segundo é que parece que os perde

Comment: @Joana se ainda não tiveres resolvido o problema faz um jsFiddle que reproduza o que tens que dou uma olhada e ajudo.

Comment: o meu código é demasiado grande e tem vários ficheiros.js e tudo interligado para só puxar isto , posso dar o link do site e consegue ver acho na console e isso

Comment: @Joana ok, coloca o link a ver se dá para ajudar

Comment: é este, obrigada 
https://projetos.epcjc.net/~i15575/pap_joana1/